# Accidentally changed my user role from Administrator to Standard in Linux Mint. Now root password doesn't match anymore

Tags: linux-mint

I have changed my root user in Linux mint from Administrator to Standard in Users and Groups menu. And now I can't do any operations that needs a root privileges simple because of my previous password doesn't accept anymore.

The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxu84.png) of the problem

How can I restore the changes?

Appreciate for any help

Comment: So just so I understand, you changed the user group of your own user, or `root`?  Your screenshot indicates you changed a username named `dimas` which wouldn't literally be root.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your reply. I don't know how but I entered in emergency mode on my Linux os. And from here I used `adduser dimas sudo` command.
And now the problem solved )

Comment: @Dimas_X You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead of commenting ...